# I can't access google play store

Tags: google-play-store

I uninstalled all updates on Google play store but won't update and says no connection. I have cleared all caches and all data.

Comment: Did you bother checking if you have a working internet connection? If you do, please mention that in the question. Also, phone and Android details are preferred.

Answer (score -2):

Try disconnecting your google account and readding it to the phone, I've had this problem as well.